# Julia: How to convert `Between(:col1, :col2)` to column index for DataFrames.DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Consider

```
using DataFrames
df=DataFrame(a=1:3, b=1:3, c=1:3)
```

and suppose I want to turn `Between(:b, :c)` into column indices, which should return `[2, 3]`?

I can `select` those columns extract the names and then call `columnindex` but that's not very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
names(df, Between(:b, :c))
```

to get the selected column names and:

```
columnindex.(Ref(df), names(df, Between(:b, :c)))
```

or (a longer but easier to read)

```
[columnindex(df, n) for n in names(df, Between(:b, :c))]
```

to get column numbers.

If you wanted something faster that is internal (i.e. not guaranteed to be working in the long term and not documented; though it it unlikely to be changed - so it is relatively safe to use):

```
DataFrames.index(df)[Between(:b, :c)]
```

A small difference between `getindex` on `DataFrames.index` and using `columnindex` is that:

- `columnindex` will return `0` for non-existent column (while `getindex` on `DataFrames.index` errors)
- you cannot pass an integer to `columnindex`, while you can pass it to `getindex` on `DataFrames.index`

Comment: would a PR for `columnindex(df, Between(:b, :c))` make sense? `columnindexes` and `columnindices` as aliases

Comment: I will comment in https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/2448.